# Can a relation have a derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In most textbooks when they talk about derivatives, they always say "derivative of a function" , but my question is, can derivatives be defined for relations other than functions? Like when one value of x gives two values of y, as in a circle or a parabola? Eg:$x^2+y^2=r^2$ or $y^2=4ax$. If they are defined for relations as well, then why is it always mentioned as derivative of a function?

Comment: Nope.  Not for relations.

Comment: Look-up "Implicit differentiation".

Comment: There are certainly ways to define the derivative of a relation (although I don't know of any ones that are standard), but I suspect that any way of defining it would lose a lot of the tools that derivatives give us making it mostly unhelpful. I can write up an explicit method of defining the derivative of a relation if you are interested.

Comment: Yes it can.  Each of the left hand side and right hand sides much vary in the same way.

Comment: @Fishbane , ok, can you please show the method you mention?

Comment: *"Like when one value of x gives two values of y, as in a circle or a parabola?"* There's a whole domain of mathematics that deals with that. If you look at the circle as a whole, then you can't write the circle as an equation looking like $y = f(x)$ nor as an equation looking like $x = f(y)$. But if you only look at a small portion of a circle, then you can always reparametrize the equation locally to make it of the form $u = f(v)$ for some variables u and v (which for instance can be x and y, or y and x).

Comment: As a conclusion, making sense of "differentiating a circle" takes a lot more theoretical work than "differentiating a function", and no one has bothered making an exact definition of "the derivative of a circle" in general, but there are contexts where you need something that looks almost like a derivative, but of something which isn't quite a function, and we do have many theorems to deal with these things.

Comment: You might also want to make a distinction between the geometrical curve on the one hand, and a particular equation to describe it on the other hand; if you and I look at the same curve and are asked to write an equation for it, we might very well write two different equations, especially if we are allowed to use parameters other than $x$ and $y$. For instance for the circle you might write the system of two equations $(x = \cos(t), y = \sin(t))$ or the implicit equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, or something else.

Comment: @Blue Ironically, your good comment arguably reinforces a _no_ answer, since implicit differentiation works only when a relation locally defines a single function. :)

Answer (score 2):

This answer has ended up being a little too technical and unhelpful, I am posting it because I still think it is interesting but it might not be of much use. For a much simpler look at derivatives of relations look up implicit differentiation as Blue mentioned in the comments.

**This first half deals with a technical definition of the derivative of a relation**

Suppose we have a function $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ and we define $y=f(x)$. We now have by the standard definition,

$$ \left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x_0}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\lim_{x_1\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}$$

This is simply the limit of the ratio of the change in $y$ corresponding to a change in $x$ for small enough changes in $x$. When considering the derivative of a relation we can see that we would need to also only allow small changes in $y$, otherwise different 'branches' of the relation would interfere and cause the derivative to be undefined.

Consider a relation $(x,y)=R\subseteq\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}$ and any point $(x_0,y_0)\in\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}$, we can give a tentative definition of the derivative as follows,

$$\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{(x_0,y_0)}=\lim_{\substack{(x_1,y_1)\rightarrow (x_0,y_0)}\\(x_1,y_1)\in R\setminus \{x_0\}\times\Bbb{R}}\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}$$

This is fine as long as $(x_0,y_0)$ is an accumulation point of $R\setminus \{x_0\}\times\Bbb{R}$, otherwise it no longer makes sense (of course the limit may not exist even if this is the case).

A little bit of checking shows that this definition agrees with the standard notion of derivative as long as $R$ is a continuous function. With a bit more care we could construct a definition which also agrees in the case of discontinuous functions, but given that the dervative would not exist classically anyway whether this is important isn't clear.

**This half deals with the concept of implicit differentiation as a tool for finding derivatives**

Sometimes a relation is defined by some equaltiy or set of equalities involving $y$ and $x$. In this case we can compute the derivative of this relation reasonably easily using the concept of implicit differentiation.

In technical terms for an equaltiy $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$ we can 'differentiate with respect to $x$' to get
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)+\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) =\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y)+ \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y)$$

This can then be solved for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at a point $(x,y)$.

In simpler terms we imagine $y$ to be a function $y(x)$ of $x$ and then differentiate the equality using standard rules and whenever we have to differentiate $y(x)$ we simply write $\frac{dy}{dx}$. There are many resources online which give a more approachable explaination of implicit differentiation, but here is a quick example.

Let $x^2+y^2=1$, then,

$$2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
and so,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$$

Finally regarding why we often do not talk about the 'derivative of a relation', the reason is that often, even when using implicit differentiation, $y$ is at least locally a function of $x$ and so we can interpret derivatives of relations as derivatives of locally defined functions. Seperately a large amount of the utility of derivative comes from certain properties they have been proven to have, but these often assume that the derivative is of a function, and so it is easier to only work in the cases where this is true.